# sum of intervals kata in codewars

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

instructions for the kata:
Write a function called sumIntervals/sum_intervals() that accepts an array of intervals, and returns the sum of all the interval lengths. Overlapping intervals should only be counted once.

Intervals
Intervals are represented by a pair of integers in the form of an array. The first value of the interval will always be less than the second value. Interval example: [1, 5] is an interval from 1 to 5. The length of this interval is 4.

Overlapping Intervals
List containing overlapping intervals:

```
[
   [1,4],
   [7, 10],
   [3, 5]
]
```

The sum of the lengths of these intervals is 7. Since `[1, 4]` and `[3, 5]` overlap, we can treat the interval as `[1, 5]`, which has a length of 4.

Examples:

```
sumIntervals( [
   [1,2],
   [6, 10],
   [11, 15]
] ) => 9

sumIntervals( [
   [1,4],
   [7, 10],
   [3, 5]
] ) => 7

sumIntervals( [
   [1,5],
   [10, 20],
   [1, 6],
   [16, 19],
   [5, 11]
] ) => 19

sumIntervals( [
   [0, 20],
   [-100000000, 10],
   [30, 40]
] ) => 100000030
```

Tests with large intervals
Your algorithm should be able to handle large intervals. All tested intervals are subsets of the range `[-1000000000, 1000000000]`.

I tried

```
def sum_of_intervals(intervals):
    total=set()
    for interval in intervals:
        for x in range(interval[0],interval[1]):
            total.add(x)
    return len(total)
```

but it doesn't work due to timed out error,could you help me with optimizing the code or can you come up with a better algorithm?

Comment: It would be helpful if you clearly identified which CodeWars challenge it was and perhaps a link to the CodeWars question.

Answer (score 1):

## Naming

> instructions for the kata:
> Write a function called `sumIntervals`/`sum_intervals()` that ...

You named your function `sum_of_intervals()`, which is not what the question asked for.

## PEP-8

The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/) recommends leaving a space around binary operators. `total=set()` should be written `total = set()`.

Additionally, it recommends a space after any comma that is followed by more content, so `range(interval[0],interval[1])` should be `range(interval[0], interval[1])`

## Readability

`interval[0]` and `interval[1]` read like they are two different intervals: interval #0 and interval #1.  You should give descriptive names to these values.  Python allows you to use a "tuple assignment"-like syntax in the `for` statement itself, making this virtually free:

```
    for interval_start, interval_end in intervals:
        for x in range(interval_start, interval_end):
```

## Use Standard Library Functions

You can add multiple items to a `set` at once.  In particular, this loop

```
        for x in range(interval_start, interval_end):
            total.add(x)
```

could be eliminated and replaced with one statement:

```
        total.update(range(interval_start, interval_end))
```

(This **should** be faster than doing the loop yourself, but always profile to make sure.)

## Updated Code

```
def sum_intervals(intervals):

    total = set()

    for interval_start, interval_end in intervals:
        total.update(range(interval_start, interval_end))

    return len(total)
```

## Algorithmic improvement

Your code's real problem is in time and space complexity.  Given the interval `[-1000000000, 1000000000]` your code will add **two billion** numbers to the `total` set.  This takes \$O(N)\$ time and \$O(N)\$ space.  In contrast, we can calculate the length of the interval in \$O(1)\$ time, in \$O(1)\$ space, using subtraction.

You've used a `set()` to handle overlaps.  Clearly, that leads to timeout error.  You need a different approach.

Consider:

```
>>> intervals = [[1, 5], [10, 20], [1, 6], [16, 19], [5, 11]]
```

Would re-ordering the intervals help you identify and remove overlaps?

```
>>> sorted(intervals)
[[1, 5], [1, 6], [5, 11], [10, 20], [16, 19]]
```

Exercise left to student.